# How to increase the height of column header in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ag-grid

> Is there a way to increase the height of the column header like we do for the width. I need this because I've embedded a piechart in header and which is binded but the column is too short to show it completely. is there a way to increase size of a column header.

Answer (score 11):

You have a property headerHeight in gridOptions

Check https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/index.php

Comment: I have, it has no effect for me :/

Comment: That was for version 3 of ag-grid, I have no idea how it should work as of now.

Answer (score 5):

### You can add run-time also according to header content using grid api:

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridApi.setHeaderHeight(<set your header height in pixel>);
}
```

bind `onGridReady()` function to gridReady event as follows:

```
<ag-grid-angular(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"> </ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 2):

Header Height property can also be set directly on the grid component in pixels like so:

```
<ag-grid-vue style="width: 100%;height: 47vh;"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
    :rowData="rowData"
    headerHeight="50">
</ag-grid-vue>
```

Answer (score 0):

check Column Headers documentation https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-header/

two options

1- properties that can be used to change the different heights

```
<ag-grid-angular
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [headerHeight]="headerHeight"
    [groupHeaderHeight]="groupHeaderHeight"
    [floatingFiltersHeight]="floatingFiltersHeight"
    [pivotGroupHeaderHeight]="pivotGroupHeaderHeight"
    [pivotHeaderHeight]="pivotHeaderHeight"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

2- setter methods that can be called from the API

```
<ag-grid-angular
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
 ></ag-grid-angular>

onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
}

setHeaderHeight(value) {
    this.gridApi.setHeaderHeight(value);
    setIdText('headerHeight', value);
}

setGroupHeaderHeight(value) {
    this.gridApi.setGroupHeaderHeight(value);
    setIdText('groupHeaderHeight', value);
}

setFloatingFiltersHeight(value) {
    this.gridApi.setFloatingFiltersHeight(value);
    setIdText('floatingFiltersHeight', value);
}

setPivotGroupHeaderHeight(value) {
    this.gridApi.setPivotGroupHeaderHeight(value);
    setIdText('pivotGroupHeaderHeight', value);
}

setPivotHeaderHeight(value) {
    this.gridApi.setPivotHeaderHeight(value);
    setIdText('pivotHeaderHeight', value);
}
```